# LinQ expression translation to EF Core (SQL Server underhood) doesn't work as expected

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core, expression

I am currently working on the endpoint that returns data about entity.

I'm using expression to project db entity to dto so it will be done on the DB side.

_repository.GetAllAsync returns IQueryable

```
 var result = await _repository.GetAllAsync(w => w.Id == entityId)
            .Select(converter)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);
```

The problem lies in the converter which is expression

```
    public static Expression<Func<Db.Models.DbEntity, DomainEntity>> Converter
        => _entityToEntityFullDetailsExpression;

    private static Expression<Func<Db.Models.DbEntity, DomainEntity>> _entityToEntityFullDetailsExpression=>
        (customer) => CopyValues(new DomainEntity(), new DomainEntity()
        {
            AdditionalField = "test";
        });
    private static DomainEntity CopyValues(DomainEntity from, DomainEntity to)
        {
            CommonField = "test";
            ....
        }
```

As I understand expression shouldn't be able to translate to sql because it's calling a method CopyValues, but it somehow works, my question is **why**?

I checked msdn but couldn't find complete documentation on how this is possible

Comment: `CopyValues` is method with compiled body which cannot be translated by EF Core. Everything should be Expression.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Yes, that's what I meant, but it's being translated and creates a query, that's why I am confused, as to my knowledge it shouldn't work

Comment: It works because last `select` partially evaluated on the client side. EF Core can detect such possibility, but if you add `Where`, `OrderBy` after `select`, it will fail.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv maybe you by any chance have a link to this documentation, i would like to dig deeper

Comment: It will fully load `DbEntity` into the memory and then apply your projection.

Comment: There is no link to documentation. It is common sense for man who is developing LINQ translator by yourself.

Comment: I can't agree with you about the statement that it fully loads DB entity, as the query generated by EF selects only top(2) records (because of singleordefault) and in the same query filtering + projection applied

Comment: Top 2 records but loads ALL fields of this entity from database. I do not state that it loads all records.

Comment: Yea, I misunderstood your statement, also not sure about all fields, as I said, for example 
generated query doesn't contain ModifedDate, but DbEntity contains it, same for all other fields I didn't touch in projections, they aren't in the query

Comment: My fault. In your case it will get from DB all mentioned fields from new `DomainEntity()
        {
            AdditionalField = "test";
        }` - second `CopyValues` parameter. IOW what is expression and translatable, will be converted to the SQL, then `CopyValues` method will be called on client side.

Comment: Thanks, it really helps, do you mind answering how did you figure it out?

Comment: How detailed explanation is needed?  Up to how ExpressionVisitor walks through MemberAccess Expressions and tries convert them to the SQL and then prepares object mapper?

Comment: I drilled down into source code and kinda understood it, so thank you